# Object Scale & Dimensions updates correctly in 3dview, but bpy.context.object.dimensions does not?

Tags: python, scripting

Could someone explain this to me?

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2)
obj = bpy.context.object
obj.location = (1, 2, 3)
obj.dimensions = (1, 2, 3)
print(obj.dimensions) # => <Vector (2.0000, 2.0000, 2.0000)>
```

I have a longer script but basically does the same thing. I'm trying to grab the obj.dimensions.z of a current obj, `bpy.context.object`, after I change it. But it keeps giving me the original value before it was changed. Even though the scale is applied. Am I missing something really obvious?? Thanks all. I am losing my mind.

[image]

Comment: bpy dimensions are for the unscaled object.  You need to apply scale in object mode if you want them to match or you need to multiply by the object's world matrix.

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean 'for the unscaled object'?? Applying the scale would give me the correct dimensions?

Comment: You're confused because I was confused.  Ignore my comment.  Sorry.

Comment: Well, dude I applied the scale and it came out correctly... bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)
print(obj.dimensions) # => <Vector (1.0000, 2.0000, 3.0000)>

Answer (score 0):

So I don't like this answer because I feel like in earlier versions you could just grab the dimensions of an object as it stood in that moment... But apparently you need to "apply the scale". Thanks Marty, even though you were confused the suggestion worked. So,

```
        obj.dimensions.z = height_block
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)

        ##### OBJ PROPERTIES ########
        #############################
        x_dimension, y_dimension, z_dimension = obj.dimensions
        print(z_dimensions) # => 3
```

If anyone can explain this better for me I'd love to understand it more in depth.